# Can I acces RDS (MySQL) in private subnet with local Spring boot Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, private-subnet, bastion-host

I have 3 databases (one RDS instance) in private subnet.
I wanna connect my local spring boot application with RDS DB (in private subnet).

I have a bastion server for checking DB.

so, I wanna connect this db with my local spring boot application then should I use bastion server?

How can I solve my issue? Thanks mates.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ec2-bastion-host/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved bros.

use Jsch(in JVM lang) sdk and tunneling
you have to need bastion server, so you can connect RDS in private subnet

Good luck bros.